# UIWebView and JavaScript: Storing an element reference, then using it later

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to build a very simple web page reader as a training project.

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Store the touched element in a JS Variable (touchedElement)
2. Later highlight a substring of that element

Unfortunately it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Here's how I try to store the touched element:

```
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    location = [aTouch locationInView:myWebView];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).innerText", location.x, location.y];
    NSString *text = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    NSString *js2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var touchedElement = document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f);", location.x, location.y];
    tagName = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js2];
```

Here's how I try to highlight a substring (Obj-C part):

```
NSString *startSearch   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uiWebview_HighlightRangeOfTouchedElement(%lu, %lu)", (unsigned long)characterRange.location, (unsigned long)characterRange.length];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];
```

Here's how I try to highlight a substring (JS part):

```
// the main entry point to start the search
function uiWebview_HighlightRangeOfTouchedElement(idx, length) {
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights();
    uiWebview_HighlightRangeOfTouchedElement(touchedElement, idx, length);
}

function uiWebview_HighlightRangeOfTouchedElement(element, idx, length)
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
            while (true) {
                //if (counter < 1) {
                var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

                //(value.split);

                //we create a SPAN element for every parts of matched keywords
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx, length));
                span.appendChild(text);

                span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
                span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                span.style.color="black";

                uiWebview_SearchResultCount++;    // update the counter

                text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
                element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
                var next = element.nextSibling;
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                element = text;
            }
        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
            if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    uiWebview_HighlightRangeOfTouchedElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword, idx, length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Obj-C part is working fine, but the JS was/is broken. Nothing to see here.